# How come dynamic binding doesnt apply here?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, dynamic-binding

I made several classes. GeoUnit is the baseclass from which County and Holding are directly extended. County however has a substructure consisting of Holdings.

When I use the toString() method of county it should display its substructure ,consisting of holdings, by calling the holdings' toString() method.
The problem lies in that I am puzzled that when I call the County's toString() method I get their regular name like "Wessex" ,while the Holding's toString() method only returns the hashcode instead of London for example.
Isn't dynamic binding applicable in the for-each loop in the toString() method of County?

EDIT 1: Wessex and London are something small that serve as an illustration.

**GeoUnit**:

```
public class GeoUnit {

private String name;
private Color RGB;
private Image COA;

public GeoUnit(String name, Color RGB, Image COA) {
    this.name = name;
    this.RGB = RGB;
    this.COA = COA;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

**County**:

```
public class County extends GeoUnit {

private int positionLandedTitles;
private GeoUnit superstruct;
private ArrayList<GeoUnit> substruct;
private String capital;

public County(int positionLandedTitles, String name, Color RGB, Image COA, ArrayList<? extends GeoUnit> substruct, String capital, GeoUnit superstruct) {
    super(name, RGB, COA);
    this.positionLandedTitles = positionLandedTitles;
    this.substruct = substruct;
    this.capital = capital;
    this.superstruct = superstruct;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    super.setName(name);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String a = "";
    for (GeoUnit g : substruct) {
        a += g.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return ("Name County: " + super.getName()+ "\n \t\t\tSubstruct: " + a);
}
```

**Holding**:

```
public class Holding extends GeoUnit {

public Holding(String name, Color RGB, Image COA) {
    super(name, RGB, COA);
    this.name=name;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
    super.setName(name);
}

@Override
public String getName(){
    return super.getName();
}
```

Comment: Why would it return London?

Comment: It is merely an example. If County is Wessex and a county consists of holdings than London might be one. But it is merely to illustrate the problem. The code here provided wouldnt show any of these two.

Comment: Why would it return anything other than what it returns (it's not really hashcode)?

Comment: Because a Holding has its own name. And if i get this name by calling the toString method I should get it and not the hashcode. No ?

Comment: Why? What does Java know about your method? What does Java know about a `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the toString() method in the Holding class. As it is not defined there, nor in the super class (GeoUnit), then the super-super class method is used (Object)

Answer (score 1):

You're invoking

```
g.toString()
```

but you haven't implemented the `toString()` method in `GeoUnit` or any of its subclasses. As such, the inherited `Object#toString()` implementation will be used.